# Kotlin delegation gradle task

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have something like this:

```
fun doSomething(specifyInput: Base.() -> Unit) {
    val spec = BaseImpl()
    spec.apply {
        specifyInput()
        validate()
    }

interface Base {
    var a: String?
    var b: String?
}

class BaseImpl(override var a: String?, override var b: String?) : Base {
    constructor() : this(null, null)
fun validate() {
        if (a == null) throw ExceptionForA()
        if (b == null) throw ExceptionForB()
    }
}
```

This is gradle task.

```
class A : DefaultTask(), Base by BaseImpl()

@TaskAction
fun doSomething() {
    doSomething {
       a = c
    }
}
```

This is my test:

```
val buildFile = File(testProjectDir, "build.gradle.kts")
        buildFile.createNewFile()
        buildFile.writeText("""
                tasks.register("task", A::class.java) {
                    c = "something"
                }
            """.trimIndent())
        val result = testProjectDir.executeAndFailGradleRunner("task")

        assertThat(result.output).contains("ExceptionForB")
```

Do you know what I need to do that the test passed?

*Thank you in advance.*

Update: In the meantime I have extend the code example.

Found the solution that I am looking for.

Comment: Inside the lambda you get a `this` receiver, you can just do `download { url = /*your url*/; target = /*your file*/ }` (in seperate lines ; is not necessary)

Comment: What do you mean? what is task here? Edit your question and summarize the problem.

Comment: I edited my question and summarized the problem.

Comment: You've to set both the variable, as if either of the variable is null then exception is raised.

Comment: I don't understand where I should set these both variables. Can you please provide example?

Comment: `doSomething { a = "something"; b = "something else" }`

Comment: I understand your point but this value "something" I passed already in my test stored in 'a' variable and I don't know how to get this value of 'a'?

Comment: Where do you want to get the variable?

Comment: In my test I have something like this:
buildFile.writeText("""
   ...
                import java.net.URL

                tasks.register("task", A::class.java) {
                    url = URL("http://somefile.txt")
                }
            """.trimIndent())
        val result = testProjectDir.executeAndFailGradleRunner("task")

Now I want to reference this url in instance of A task.

Comment: Man you never mentioned what is `tasks` in `tasks.register` I already asked in one of the comments...

Comment: class A : DefaultTask() this class is the gradle task

Comment: There is no register function in [DefaultTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html), how are you even calling `tasks.register()`? I'm flagging question as very low quality, you're not able to ask question or answer what is asked properly.

Comment: Can you then explain me why when I execute this tasks.register("task", A::class.java) in other test the test is passed?

Comment: `if (a == null) throw RuntimeException() if (b == null) throw RuntimeException()` You're checking both variable must not be null and you're only passing only 1 variable `url` other is null by default and hence RuntimeException is raised as it should be.

Comment: If I understood you well you want to say that I cannot call the task and passed the value like this:
tasks.register("task", A::class.java) {
                    a = URL("somefile.txt")
                }

Comment: You have to set `b` as well if you want the test to be succeed. +_+

Comment: But in this test case I expect to throw Exception because I want to pass a but not b and I have validation for a and b. But the problem is that is a is also null what I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I have to use another variable and assign in my variable from delegation, a = c, cannot use a = a.